# Create a new mongoose object with optional parameters from a request

Tags: node.js, express, object, mongoose, schema

I have a fairly long and complicated nested objected with optional objects inside (see below). I have a request coming in that could have some fields/objects missing - how can I handle that? Can I just use the "?" operand - I have tried but can't seem to get it working. Is there another method I could try?

```
const product = new Product({
 prodID: req.body.prodID,
 prodComponents: {
   textComponent :{
      item: req.body.prodComponents.textComponent.item ? req.body.prodComponents.textComponent.item : null
   }
   imageComponent:{
      item: req.body.prodComponents.imageComponent.item ? req.body.prodComponents.imageComponent.item : null
   }
 }
)};
```

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways to resolve your problem. The variable: `req.body` is just another object as almost everything in javascript.

I'd recommend taking that object and parse it into variables or other object that your program or data model will handle with no exceptions of access into empty or undefined fields.

```
function createProductDtoToProduct(data) {
    const model = {
        prodID: data.prodID,
        prodComponents: {
            textComponent: {
                item: null
            },
            imageComponent: {
                item: null
            }
        }
    };

    if (data.prodComponents && data.prodComponents.textComponentItem)
        model.prodComponents.textComponent.item = {
            id: data.textComponentItem.id,
            title: prodComponents.textComponentItem.title || "defaultTitle",
        }
    if (data.prodComponents && data.prodComponents.imageComponentItem)
        model.prodComponents.imageComponent.item = {
            id: data.imageComponentItem.id,
            title: prodComponents.imageComponentItem.title || "defaultTitle",
        }
    return model;
}

router.post("/createProduct", async (req, res) => {
    const product = new Product(createProductDtoToProduct(req.body));
    await db.save(product);

    return "OK";
});
```

Also you can validate the body of the request with many tools such as:

https://express-validator.github.io/docs/